# Invisible directory names

Tags: command-line, filesystems, ls, directory-listing

When I do `ls -l` I get the picture below and I have no idea why. I know the names of the directories and I can `cd` to them no problem but can't see the actual names. How do I fix that?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable it temporally by putting `\` before the command,

```
$ \ls -la
```

Alternativly, you can disable it for good by modifying the file `~/.bashrc`
Just commend the below line with `#`.

```
#alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

and execute the command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```